# Regex to pick all occurrences of certain word

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to pick every __custom_field:something on this string

```
${__active_activity_report/__custom_field:matrix_on_list/__custom_field:matrix_integer}
```

my best attempt was `(\/.*?(custom_field).*\/|)` but im failling to catch the case where it doesnt end with a `/` but with a `}` , i tried or cases but i might be doing it wrong;

Comment: What about `/__custom_field:\w+/g` or `/_+custom_field:\w+/g`? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yVFkwa/1).

Comment: `(__custom_field\:[\w_]+)`  Try https://regex101.com/r/0el5fJ/1

Comment: @PM77-1 `[\w_]` = `\w`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I thought explicit would be clearer...  You are right anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/__custom_field:\w+/g
/_+custom_field:\w+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yVFkwa/1).

*Details*:

- `__custom_field:` - a fixed string
- `\w+` - one or more letters/digits/*underscores*.

The `_+` part matches one or more underscores (in case you have `_custom`, `__custom`, `___custom`, etc.)